# Откуда берется undefined массив?

Tags: массивы, javascript

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  var myArray = ["abc", "cba", "bca", "acb"];
  var i;
  var text;
  for (i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    text += "<p>" + myArray[i] + "</p>";
        document.body.innerHTML = text;
    }
  //-->
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Недавно начал изучать javascript, решил попробовать перебрать элементы с помощью цикла и обнаружил, что откуда-то берется пятый элемент со значением undefined. Почему так происходит и как это можно исправить (желательно без оператора if)?

Comment: это на первой итерации

>> text += "<p>" + myArray[i] + "</p>";

аналогично этому

>> text = undefined + "<p>" + myArray[i] + "</p>";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В массиве "undefined" нету. А берется она оттуда, где переменная не определена:

```
var text = '';
```

Comment: Теперь ясно, спасибо!